# How to setup schema registry for multiple event types in the same kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

According to https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.3/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-json.html#multiple-event-types-in-the-same-topic I have to define top-level schema using `oneOf`:

```
{
  "oneOf": [
     { "$ref": "Customer.schema.json" },
     { "$ref": "Product.schema.json" },
     { "$ref": "Order.schema.json }
  ]
}
```

Next they say that I should send an array of reference versions and this is the part I don't understand. How should I do it exactly?

Can someone show full example how to submit this schema to schema registry using `curl`?

Answer (score 0):

Should clarify that topics don't have schemas. Clients define subject strategies to pull ids from the registry.

So, if you use something other than TopicNameStategy, the default, then you'll naturally end up with multiple typed records sent into one topic.

If you use Jsonschema `oneOf` or Avro/Protobuf union types in one schema. That's still only "one type" encompassing multiple options for the deserializer to determine.

In any case, rather than curl, perhaps you may find the [Schema Registry Gradle plugin](https://github.com/ImFlog/schema-registry-plugin/blob/master/examples/json/build.gradle) more useful, or simply let your producer automatically register the schema on the first request, as the documentation shows.